# How do I create spreadsheet that will alert me when a quantity drops below a certain threshold in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to make a sort of "inventory helper" spreadsheet that can track quantities.  On the summary sheet, I want to be able to enter a quantity into a column called "On Hand" and then if that number is under an established threshold (which will be different depending on the item the row is for) a column further across will display a yellow and/or red message informing whoever is using the sheet that they need to order more of said-item.  Perhaps taking this one step beyond, there would be another column which takes the difference between the required amount and the quantity on hand so that it would display exactly how many more of the item needs to be ordered, too.
I've seen some spreadsheets that do things similar to this, but I have absolutely no idea how to do it myself.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using [conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f?ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US)?

Comment: What have you tried so we rule out the possible solutions you already tried but ruled out.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is called Conditional formatting in Excel.  Since you are talking on different thresholds for each item, it will be best to have a threshold column as well so you can change what the threshold will be in the future easily.  I could go into great detail on how to do this, however, there is a great place where this is already documented at: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/05/excel-conditional-formatting-icon-sets-data-bars-color-scales/.  This tells you not only on how to do the conditional formatting, but also on what different types of formatting is available to you, and applies to not only Excel 2010, but also from Excel 2007 to currently 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off doing this in Microsoft Access. If you must use Excel, understand the [risks of using Excel](http://www.waspbarcode.com/buzz/4-reasons-excel-inventory-management-doesnt-work/), primarily data entry errors.

You want to think about some Excel columns here:

- ReOrder Point - when stock balance reach this number, the inventory must be reordered
- Lead Time - how many days does it take to receive your inventory
- Safety Stock - qty required for unforeseen requirements
- Economic Order Quantity (EOQ) - min qty required by vendor, or qty for discount

Advanced technique is to use units sold per day to figure when you need to order more based on the lead time.

Here are some [specifics on how to manage inventory with Excel](http://www.jameshbyrd.com/manage-your-inventory-in-excel/). It is a bunch of if-then type logic where it calculates some of the concepts I described above.